# Loading configuration resource to Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Since I'm running out of ideas (and stackoverflow threads): I need an additional app configuration, located under `/etc/appname/config.yml` (client requirement).

My configuration file:

```
foo: 'bar'
```

I'm loading this file within my `app/config/config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: /etc/appname/config.yml }
```

The error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "foo"

I've already implemented a `Configuration` class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder =  new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('foo')->defaultValue('')->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

But it still doesn't work. If I load the config via the `load` method

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator('/etc/frsereportergui')
    );

    $loader->load('config.yml');
}
```

I get the same error.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: You likely need a 'root' `$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('foo');`, and then the configuration withn the block.  Or should it be in a `parameter:` section?

Comment: Should be a parameters section. But even if I try to use "foo" as a root element and attach some children - it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you want it to be a parameter then add the parameters section header to your file and place foo under it.  If you actually wanted to use real configuration then you need a bundle with an alias of foo.  It is all explained in the docs.